# Ruby - updating large amounts of data into Postgres DB on Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a Ruby application Postrgress DB on heroku.
Some of the data is was migrated incorrectly.
I want to update the data on about 5 thousand rows. I do not want to blow the DB away and remigrate.
What would be the best way to do this. 
I have update small amounts of data using the active record type sql but not sure for a large amount.

thanks in advance

Maggs

Comment: Five thousand rows shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how many fields or what type of data you specifically you are trying to change.

Are your fields changing specifically for each one or are you able to run a loop to iterate through each row to update the value?  Please be more specific in terms of the data and what kind of editing you are trying to do.

Comment: all individual values. I am not sure what you mean by what type of editing so I am not sure if this will answer your question: updating an integer value which I have in a csv file and to replace the existing value which I pulled down from online